# Execute Curl from Java

Tags: java, curl

I am trying to execute the following curl command from Java, but the answer I get is incorrect, since it always returns the status 401.

```
curl -k -v -u "admin2:0xdRv63RKq2MtA326BNGQAI6yA1QNGO09enamGxI" -d "{"username":"test","token_code":"246212"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://192.168.101.59/api/v1/auth/
```

I am sending correctly the user "admin2" with his password for the authentication. I think the problem is the use of character (") in my code.

```
String[] command = {"curl", "-k", "-v", "-u","admin2:0xdRv63RKq2MtA326BNGQAI6yA1QNGO09enamGxI",
                "-d", "{\"username\":\"test\",\"token_code\":\"246212\"}","-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "https://192.168.101.59/api/v1/auth/"};

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

String curlResult = "";
String line = "";

try {
    Process process = builder.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    while (true) {
        line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }
        curlResult = curlResult + line;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 'command', try removing the single quotes from

```
"'admin2:0xdRv63RKq2MtA326BNGQAI6yA1QNGO09enamGxI'"
```

so that it becomes

```
"admin2:0xdRv63RKq2MtA326BNGQAI6yA1QNGO09enamGxI"
```

and see if that helps. It might be considering them as part of the actual username and password.

I think the issue is the Json in this case and I think you are right then that the double quotes are the issue. Try putting the Json in a file and use curl to send the file contents as the body of your message.

```
String[] command = {"curl", "-k", "-v", "-u","admin2:0xdRv63RKq2MtA326BNGQAI6yA1QNGO09enamGxI",
            "-d", "@/path/to/filename.json", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "https://192.168.101.59/api/v1/auth/"};
```

Comment: I'm so sorry. I had tried with "admin2:0xdRv63RKq2MtA326BNGQAI6yA1QNGO09enamGxI" but the response is the same

Comment: No, the service's response is the same (status 401).

Comment: @BrayanReyes Edited my response. If you can't live with the json in a file then you'll need to do further research on escaping a json payload in curl.

Comment: forgive me for the delay. I tried your code and solved my problem. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: @BrayanReyes Awesome, glad that worked for you! Also, if you'd kindly accept this answer I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!