# Can cmd curl and java.net.http.HttpClient be used together in Java?

Tags: java, curl, cmd, httpclient

I'm trying to understand how cmd `curl` and `HttpClient(java.net.http.*)` class can work together in Java..

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/team")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8081")
public class TeamController {
    @Autowired
    TeamService teamService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> addNewTeam(@RequestBody Team newTeam) {
        Team team = new Team();
        try {
            team= teamService.addNewTeam(newTeam);
        } catch(TeamAlreadyExistException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(team, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllTeams() {
        List<Team> teams = teamService.getAllTeams();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(teams, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
}
```

If I have a Controller like this in my project and just by using cmd curl itself,
I can get the desired outcome I want.. like this below..

```
MyPath>curl -X GET "http://localhost:8081/api/team"
[{"id":1,"name":"team3"}]
```

I'm trying not to use Postman and try to work with HttpClient Class and Cmd..And I think
If I have @RestController and the cmd.. http request is just find without HttpClient..
Is there any way that I can incorporate HttpClient when trying to make a Http Request Call to my TeamController??

Comment: Would you mind re-phrasing your entire question? Is pretty unclear what you are actually asking - you're demonstrating the correct usage of self-written Spring REST controllers with a CURL client and ... want to know how you did that (?)

Also : i recommend using a proper translator-service like DeepL - you're obviously struggling with the english language, thats very OK. Just try to use available services; we all do.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I know that I can use curl to do http request to Spring REST controllers. I just wonder if I can add one more step to this process, which is using HttpClient Class. Just by using curl, I can communicate directly with Spring Rest Controller. Can I use cmd to control Rest Client I make with Http Client Class and this Http Client Class can go to Spring Rest Controller?

Comment: Im afraid your sentences are somewhat unintelligible. Please use some kind of translator service.
Are you trying to start HTTP calls in the REST controller-method or do you want to redirect certain calls to the REST method to another controller .... ?

Comment: I want to redirect certain calls to the REST method to another controller. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: You can do it all, and you can do it using curl. But the complexity will eat your energy. Use a proper library for that.

Answer (score 0):

Of course a java application can do http requests by executing curl. See [Execute Curl from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638990/execute-curl-from-java).

But I guess the effort of integrating curl outperforms direct handling of HTTP requests in Java. You have better performance and control over the communication altogether.

I've had quite some success using [Apache httpclient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.1.x/).

Comment: Thanks! So either using cmd curl or using Apache httpclient(or other libraries like RestTemplate), right?

Comment: You can also use the Java builtin class HttpUrlConnection, if you do not like to add other libraries. But yes, you understood right.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently what you actually are looking for is this :
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward

```
 @GetMapping("/redirectWithRedirectPrefix")
public ModelAndView redirectWithUsingRedirectPrefix(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("attribute", "redirectWithRedirectPrefix");
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/redirectedUrl", model);
}
```